# Sendmail to send contents of error.log

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, email

`Ubuntu`:
I am trying to send an email with `sendmail`, `mailx`, or `mail` (anything that will work). I am trying to send the contents of a log file as the message. Log located at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

I am running a cron every hour to see if anything in the error log changed and if it has I am trying to send the error log to myself in an email. A regular test with sendmail and mailx and mail work just fine for me.

This **works** (but not what I want):
`echo "My test email being sent from sendmail" | /usr/sbin/sendmail email@gmail.com`

I tried the following (none of them work for me):
`sendmail email@gmail.com < /var/log/nginx/error.log`,
`/var/log/nginx/error.log | /usr/sbin/sendmail email@gmail.com`,
`cat /var/log/nginx/error.log | /usr/sbin/sendmail email@gmail.com`,
`mailx email@gmail.com < /var/log/nginx/error.log`,
`cat /var/log/nginx/error.log | mailx email@gmail.com`

Obviously a newbie here.

Comment: You don't expect many errors. If you had a real problem, your error log will grow to big to send by email. Rather think about sending only the last few kB.

Comment: What Lorenz said.  You might want to consider something like LogWatch instead.

Comment: Be careful as you're sending sensitive data about your server across the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail expects to get email headers and body over its stdin.
[email headers + empty line + email body ]
Your attempts failed to provide headers.

Try the script below:

```
#!/bin/sh
( 
   echo subject: /var/log/nginx/error.log
   echo  
   cat /var/log/nginx/error.log 
) | sendmail -i email@gmail.com
```